# Как получить json файл в React Native expo и вывести в FlatList?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

Идет вечная загрузка и не отображается контент.

Ошибка в консоли хром
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
       // let ds = new FlatList.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.movies),
        }, function() {
          // do something with new state
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text> {item.Begin} </Text> }
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какова цель использования `DataSource` и `cloneWithRows`?  Правильно ли я понимаю - Вам нужно получить объект и вывести массив `movies`? Вы можете передать массив непосредственно в компонент:

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@ihor.pavlenko/joyous-juice-box)

```js
import React, { memo, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // const ds = new FlatList.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
        setIsLoading(false);
        setData(responseJson);
      }, () => {
        // do something with new state
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     { 
       isLoading &&   
       <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      }
       { 
        !isLoading && 
          <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
            <FlatList
              data={data?.movies}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              ListHeaderComponent={() => (
                <View>
                  <Text style={{ color: 'blue', fontSize: 28, }}>{data?.title}</Text>
                  <Text style={{ color: 'brown', fontSize: 18, }}>{data?.description}</Text>
                </View>
              )}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
                  {` - ${item?.title}: ${item?.releaseYear}`}
                </Text>
              )}
            />
          </View>
       }
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 14,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Comment: В json сейчас только один массив, а их будет много в этом файле. Вывести нужно по отдельности эти массивы.

Comment: А если json будет такого вида? Как настроить? `{
  "title": "Kotori",
  "link": "charge.html",
  "category": "Dubstep",
  "image": "charge.jpg",
} 
{
  "title": "Tisoki",
  "link": "royce.html",
  "category": "Trap",
  "image": "royce.jpg",
}`

Comment: И почему маленький массив выводит, а большой нет. 4 строки нормально, а уже 5 не выводит?

Comment: по п.1 - нужен пример json'a. Если это будет массив массивов, то тоже не вижу проблем с передачей во FlatList.

Comment: по п.2. -  такой json не должен приходить, это не корректная структура и должна быть ошибка.  Какой вид должен иметь json, вы можете ознакомится на https://www.json.org/json-en.html. Скорее всего - это будет или массив объектов или объект с объектами в качестве значений. Во втором случае просто сделайте Object.values(obj)

Comment: по п.3. - без конкретики сложно понять, что не так.  Возможно что-то с extraData, может стоит initialNumToRender={4} и т.д.

Comment: В принципе я могу сделать любой конструкции json. Главное вывести массивы как в п.2, таких данных будет много. Какой вид лучше сделать?

Comment: [https://snack.expo.io/@segalap76/joyous-juice-box] Я поменял только json, с таким же видом

Comment: У вас не валидный json, поэтому он и не парсится - лишняя запятая после последнего элемента в массиве. Воспользуйтесь сервисом  http://json.parser.online.fr/ и проверьте там ваш json.